# Serverless doesn't include `pg` dependency / Internal error with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, serverless

I'm currently struggling with the deployment of my GraphQL serverless function. Everything is working perfectly locally, the database is reachable publicly, but I realized that the application was crashing after deployment because pg dependency is not added properly (it's in my package.json)

When I'm deploying the serverless Application without adding `var pg = require('pg')` in my code, it's omitting this dependency. On the other hand, when `var pg = require('pg')` is added somewhere (even not used), the package is included in the zip output of serverless. I've still got the exception message, when it's included manually (`var pg = require('pg')`) and not used directly in the app (as I'm connecting to postgres using sequelize instance).

My database is accessible publicly (for dev staging), and I can use it locally; I installed pg manually locally and it's appearing in `node_modules`, but when I'm deploying it's not packed with the zip file containing my app.

Anyone had such issue in the past?

Comment: is it in your `devDependencies` in your `package.json`?

Comment: No, in my direct dependencies, I'm using webpack to compile the App (in TypeScript) and I've set the option `webpackIncludeModules`